# How to dump an xml file generated from server to a random client, but I have to damp that file in a specific folder of clients

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, windows-services

I was thinking to dump an XML file generated from server to a random client requesting that. The problem is that I have to damp that file in a specific folder of clients (**C:/Application/POSMachine/WaitingXML**), for there is another application listening to that folder.

***My approach***:

1. A simple patch (to change chrome download address to the specific desired path)
2. Installing windows service/local-api for those clients who need this feature, and passing server-side generated XML to clients installed service/api, I am assuming I will get clients IP-address from the server and hit the service hosted in clients.

> Request.GetOwinContext().Request.RemoteIpAddress

Any comments and better implementation is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It would be a security risk to allow a website to download a file to an arbitrary location (that would mean a malicious website could just download a new svchost.exe to C:\Windows\System32 or what not)

Also your idea with running a service would not work in all cases, since your clients will most probably be behind a modem/router/NAT switch (or multiple). All these devices would have to be configured for port forwarding. So, you really need an 'client-outbound' connection (like a browser does).

I would implement a client program which can contact your server and download the file with a `System.Net.WebRequest` and save to the specific location. Another possibility might be to add a `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` control and handle the `FileDownload` event. However, your question does not contain enough information to more specific (how does the client chose a file to download)

Comment: That is also a good way to use clients polling from a download address link, that will pretty much solve my problem but I am worried about the timing, like when a user clicks a 'check-out' button a receipt should be generated via the POS-Machine (w/ch this machine will be triggered to print whenever there is a new XML file in a certain directory ). As my system is in web-based I just wanted to hand-over the XML response each clients get after a checkout action to locally installed WebService/API